# How to call edit method of the resource controller using AJAX in Laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

In my laravel project I am using resource controller.for insert,update,delete etc.And I want all the operations using the ajax call.Add ,delete are done but in edit URL not working properly.

```
function show_edit_modal(url,id)
{
    $('#add_item').modal('show');
    $('#hidden_model').append('<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">');
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "makes/6/edit",
           data:{id:id},
           success: function (data) {
           console.log(data);
           }       
        });  
}
```

Here In this method I am showing the edit form and calling the edit method to fetch the edit data but it calls the last part of url (edit) only.

[image]

Comment: It seems that your route is not getting called. Simply copy the URL and try post method using RESTClient or post-man and check if the method is getting called?

Comment: By the way you should read more about using POST method in laravel. You also sould pass laravel's token when using post method. Of course when using get method you don't have to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "makes/6/edit",
          data:{id:id},
          success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
          }      
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,Below i am sending all the data into the arry And make sure that your route name should be given properly.`

```
           var postdata={};
            postdata['id']= $('#id').val();
            postdata["_token"]= $('input[name=_token]').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'route name',
            type: "post",
            data: postdata,
            success: function (data) {
               //success Logic
            },
            error: function (data) {
               //failur logic

            }                
        })
    }`
```